# std::function<void()> constructor with std::bind

Tags: c++, function, bind, auto

```
std::function<void()> f = std::function<void()>(std::bind(fn,params));
```

fn - LPVOID type, params - std::vector
I have an error here.C2064:term does not evaluate to a function taking 'number' arguments.

This error arise in functional.h!

I know, that i should better write something like

```
auto f = std::bind(fn,params);
```

But my task is to store lots of func pointers in a std::queue.

How can i transorm std::bind() to a specific type (or store "auto" type)?

Comment: The first one should work, but would work better without the redundant type.

Comment: The first argument to `bind` needs to be some sort of function. LPVOID hardly fits that requirement.

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `fn` ?

Comment: Consider storing a lambda functor instead of a `::std::bind` functor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error: term does not evaluate to a function taking 'number' arguments

The error message may be referring to your parameter `fn` which, as a `LPVOID`, is not a function at all.